# what is wrong here? associativity? evaluation order? how to change order?

Tags: c++

The associativity of stream insertion operator is rtl, forgetting this fact sometimes cause to runtime or logical errors.
for example:

1st-

```
int F()
{
   static int internal_counter c=0;
   return ++c;
}
```

in the main function:

```
//....here is main()
cout<<”1st=”<<F()<<”,2nd=”<<F()<<”,3rd=”<<F();
```

and the output is:

```
1st=3,2nd=2,3rd=1
```

that is different from what we expect at first look.

2nd-
suppose that we have an implementation of stack data structure like this:

```
    //
    //... a Stack<DataType> class …… 
    //

    Stack<int> st(10);
    for(int i=1;i<11;i++)
       st.push(i);

cout<<st.pop()<<endl<<st.pop()<<endl<<st.pop()<<endl<<st.pop()<<endl;
```

expected output is something like:

```
10
9
8
7
```

but we have:

```
7
8
9
10
```

There is no internal bug of << implementation but it can be so confusing... 
and finally[:-)] my question: is there any way to change associativity of an operator by overloading it?

do you think this could be not reverse? i mean is it possible to change order by modifying or changing an open source STL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only things that are right-associative are the assignment operators. See §5.4 to 5.18 of the standard. The `<<` operators are evaluated left-to-right or the messages would be backward in grammar, not in content. The content is due to side effects, which are unordered in C++ except (as Neil mentions) for "short-circuit" && and ||, and comma.

Answer (score 10):

No there isn't. But I think you may be mixing up associativity with evaluation order. The only operators that specify an evalualtion order are &&, || and , (comma). When you say:

```
cout<<st.pop()<<endl<<st.pop()<<endl<<st.pop()<<endl<<st.pop()<<endl;
```

the compiler can evaluate sub-expressions such as st.pop() in any order it likes, which is what causes the unexpected output.

Answer (score 2):

To see how this is an order of evaluation issue and not an associativity issue, modify your code to this:

```
int a = st.pop();
int b = st.pop();
int c = st.pop();
cout << a << endl << b << endl << c << endl;
```